# How do I count the number of true Boolean values inside an array within a collection and group by job in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Given:** I am given a collection that contains information for a batch.

**Expectation:** I need to return the number of true values for a job.

**Some context:** Every Job is split up into multiple batches. In the collection: The `labellers` contains an array where the `labeller` is the user and the completed says whether of not a person has completed the batch, the `_id` refers to the batch id, the job contains the `_id` of a specific job.

So I know I need to unwind and group by jobs but I just can't seem to get my query to return the correct number of true values.

**The collection:**

```
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("612370c2abbe776854d8c0ec"),
    "batch_number": 0,
    "job": ObjectId("612370c1abbe777ae8d8c0eb"),
    "labellers": [
      {
        "labeller": ObjectId("61238ed4abbe77763ed8c100"),
        "completed": true
      },
      {
        "labeller": ObjectId("61238f2babbe77c838d8c101"),
        "completed": true
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("612370c2abbe771a75d8c0ed"),
    "batch_number": 1,
    "job": ObjectId("612370c1abbe777ae8d8c0eb"),
    "labellers": [
      {
        "labeller": ObjectId("61238ed4abbe77763ed8c100"),
        "completed": true
      },
      {
        "labeller": ObjectId("61238f2babbe77c838d8c101"),
        "completed": false
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
```

**Desired output**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("612370c1abbe777ae8d8c0eb"),
    "count": 3
  }
```

What I have tried:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $unwind: "$labellers"
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$job",
    count: {
      $sum: {
        $cond: [
          {
            "labellers": {
              "completed": true
            }
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The output on what I have tried:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("612370c1abbe777ae8d8c0eb"),
    "count": 4
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `labellers.completed` booleans array and filter true result
- `$size` to get total elements return in above filter operation
- `$group` by `job` and sum total elements count

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$job",
      count: {
        $sum: {
          $size: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$labellers.completed",
              cond: "$$this"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jUmOCnrMJB3)

Comment: Thanks for you answer it worked amazingly. Just out of interest, how would this change if I wanted to count the false, I tired using `$ne` in the `cond` line and it didn't work.

Comment: You can use `$not` operator for negative condition, [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/75DIclv7_Gs)

Answer (score 0):

I add `$match` before `$group` and remove `$cond` from `$group`

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'job': '612370c1abbe777ae8d8c0eb'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$labellers'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'labellers.completed': true
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$job', 
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```